# Azure Pipeline - Job depending on last Job, but last job is part of a loop based on parameter array

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have something like this:

```
   - ${{ each workItem in parameters.workList }}:
    - job: '{{workItem.Name}}_${{ parameters.poolObj.Name }}_${{ parameters.agentName }}'
        ...

   - job: 'Clean_up':
        ...
```

How can I make Clean_up depends on the last job, since the last job it's dynamic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I want to point out that it is possible to define custom `displayName` for each job. That value will be displayed in each run. By default it is the same as `id`. In your example you used complex `id` value, that would make solution much more complex.
Here is simple scenario:

```
parameters:
  - name: workList
    type: object
    default: [FirstThing, SecondThing, ThirdThing]
  - name: poolObj
    default: MyMachines
  - name: agentName
    default: customAgent

jobs:
  - ${{ each workItem in parameters.workList }}:
    - job: '${{workItem}}'
      steps:
        - script: echo 'Doing some things...'
      displayName: ${{workItem}}_${{ parameters.poolObj }}_${{ parameters.agentName }}

  - job: cleanup
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.workList }}
    steps:
      - script: echo doing cleanup
```

In example above, I changed id for jobs in the loop to just `workItem`. That should still produce unique job ids because `poolObj` and `agentName` parameters are not depend on current `workItem`. But it will still show full name in run results.
`cleanup` job depends on whole `workList` array and it will work because all jobs have same id as items in that array.

It would be more complicated solution if for some reason we will use job ids which are result of concatenation of few parameters. Here is what I came up with:

```
parameters:
  - name: workList
    type: object
    default: [FirstThing, SecondThing, ThirdThing]
  - name: poolObj
    default: MyMachines
  - name: agentName
    default: customAgent

jobs:
  - ${{ each workItem in parameters.workList }}:
    - job: '${{workItem}}_${{ parameters.poolObj }}_${{ parameters.agentName }}'
      steps:
        - script: echo '${{workItem}}_${{ parameters.poolObj }}_${{ parameters.agentName }}'

  - job: cleanup
    dependsOn: ${{ split(format('{0}_{1}_{2}', join(format('_{0}_{1};', parameters.poolObj, parameters.agentName), parameters.workList), parameters.poolObj, parameters.agentName), ';') }}
    steps:
      - script: echo doing cleanup
```

Here I am joining parameter array and splitting it back to generate transformed array.